# Unable to connect HDFS with Go hdfs client

Tags: go, hdfs, kerberos

I am getting the below error while trying to connect HDFS with Go hdfs client - colinmarc. Does any one have a clue on why the error is coming?

```
import (
    "github.com/colinmarc/hdfs/v2"
    "github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8/client"
    "github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8/config"
    "github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8/keytab"
)

// krb5client variable is pointing to keytab file and krb5.conf file

    options := hdfs.ClientOptions{
        Addresses:                    []string{"namenode1:8020", "namenode2:8020"},
        User:                         "myid",
        NamenodeDialFunc:             nil,
        DatanodeDialFunc:             nil,
        KerberosClient:               krb5client,
        KerberosServicePrincipleName: "nn/_HOST@REALM.COM",
    }

    client, err := hdfs.NewClient(options)
```

//Error
*Error while connecting to HDFS: no available namenodes: SASL handshake: [Root cause: KDC_Error] KDC_Error: TGS Exchange Error: kerberos error response from KDC when requesting for nn/hostname@REALM.COM: KRB Error: (7) KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN Server not found in Kerberos database*